# Edit/Update xml with C# in windows phone application

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I intend to create a windows phone application (c# & XML)  that reads a local xml file, publish the data in a textbox and then the user  can change the data and save the xml file. I need some guidance on how to do this (not the code, only the idea).
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like XmlWriter?  Here's a good article on it http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/tips/All-about-WP7-Isolated-Storage---Read-and-Save-XML-files-using-XmlWriter .

If this one doesn't work for you post back to the thread.

Comment: thnks Joe! i've read that article but it's a little  confusing for me as i'm new to programming. I'll try again!

Comment: post a sample of the data structure you want to read and write.  I'll write a code sample to do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the XML file has a pre-defined schema, you may be best to use the xsd.exe command to import that schema into your application.  Then you can deserialize the local XML file into an in memory object(s), edit that object's properties and fields, and then serialize the in memory object(s) back to disk.

References:

- [XSD Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)
- [Serialize and Deserializing XML](http://geekswithblogs.net/paulwhitblog/archive/2007/07/20/114076.aspx)

Comment: Thanks corith for your sugestion!

Answer (score 0):

To use Isolated and LINQ reference and guide below.

LINQ
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933

Isolated
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.aspx